# Cisco IP forwading challenge on a cisco router

Tags: static, ip, nat, portforwarding

I have been trying to setup a cisco gateway router that has a Mail server behind it. The challenge has been that the static nat entries are no effective or perhaps do not work. Has anyone done this in areal life environment? testing for open ports shows that all the static NAT ports are closed .Please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Actually found out that the problem was the gateway on the mail server that was still pointing to the old ISP instead of the router connecting to the new ISP.

Comment: Good for you! If it's fixed you should close the question or remove it :^)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp LAN_MAIL_IP_ADDRESS 25 MAIL_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS 25 extendable
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
   description "TO INTERNET"
   ip nat outside
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
   description "TO LAN"
   ip nat inside
```